# Append data to relevant sheets based on condition in parent sheet using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Append data from one sheet to relevant sheet if not already present,based on condition:

I am trying to append data in Column A in sheet "Export", to Column A in sheet "pass" or to Column A in sheet "fail" based on value in Column B(either pass/fail) in Sheet 1.

I have the code for appending data if not found, but it appends to all sheets, ignoring the filter completely.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim c As Range, f As Range
    Dim ws1, ws3

    Set ws1 = Worksheets(1)
    Set ws3 = Worksheets(3)

    For Each c In ws1.Range(ws1.Range("A1"), ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Cells

' The next line doesn't work
' If Range("B" & c).Value = "Calendar" Then

        Set f = ws3.Range(ws3.Range("A1"), _
                           ws3.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Find( _
                                      What:=c.Value, lookat:=xlWhole)

        If f Is Nothing Then
            ws3.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 3).Value = _
                                                        c.Resize(1, 3).Value
        End If
End If
    Next c

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify the below code and try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim f As Range
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet
    Dim c As Long '<- Change c as long NOT range

    Set ws1 = Worksheets(1) '<- Note: Here you refer to sheet with index number 1, NOT in sheet called Sheet1
    Set ws3 = Worksheets(3) '<- Note: Here you refer to sheet with index number 3, NOT in sheet called Sheet3

    For c = 1 To ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row '<- Loop row by row, starting from 1 to last row of columnA

        If ws1.Range("B" & c).Value = "Calendar" Then

            Set f = ws3.Range(ws3.Range("A1"), _
                               ws3.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Find( _
                                          What:=ws1.Range("B" & c).Value, lookat:=xlWhole) '<- Change What

                If f Is Nothing Then

                    ws3.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 3).Value = ws1.Range("B" & c)

                End If
        End If
    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: I modified the code values accordingly, but i get a type mismatch error.

Comment: The type msmatch error is a pop up and does not give an exact lin number, but i am assuming it might be from ws1.Range("A" & c).Value, ?